# Find volume of cask

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was given the following question:

A wine cask has a radius at the top of $30 cm$ and a radius at the middle of $40 cm$.
The height of the cask is $1m$.
What is the volume of the cask in litres, assuming the shape of the side is parabolic?

I have to come to parabolic function of

$$y = \frac{-1}{250}(x-50)^2+40$$

The derivative of $y$ is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2}{5} - \frac{x}{125}$$

Then I integrate and end up with an expression the length of $\pi$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you do not need the derivative, but the following article might answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution

Answer (score 2):

We place the centre of the cask at the origin, and assume that the cask is symmetrical about its mid-plane.

Consider the parabola $y=40-kx^2$. At $x=50$ we want $y=30$. So $k=\frac{10}{2500}=\frac{1}{250}$.

We will rotate this parabola about the $x$-axis. The resulting solid is the cask.

It is useful to integrate from $x=0$ to $x=50$, and double. By the usual formula, the volume, in cubic cm, is
$$2\int_0^{50}\pi\left(40-\frac{x^2}{250}\right)^2\,dx.$$

**Remark:** Kepler once wrote a little book about how to compute the volumes of Austrian wine casks. The book did not sell well, and Kepler had to go back to casting horoscopes and theorizing about the motions of the planets.

Answer (score 2):

All lengths should be in the same units, say metres.

Let the radius $r$ of the cask, at height $h$ above the ground have equation $r=ah^2+bh+c$.

When $h=0$ we want $r=\frac{3}{10}$. When $h=\frac{1}{2}$ we want $r=\frac{4}{10}$. When $h=1$ we want $r=\frac{3}{10}$.

Putting these into $r=ah^2+bh+c$ and solving the three simultaneous equations in $a,b,c$ gives
$$r = \frac{3}{10}+\frac{2}{5}h-\frac{2}{5}h^2$$

Using the [formula for the volume of revolution](http://www.mathsrevision.net/advanced-level-maths-revision/pure-maths/calculus/volumes-revolution), we get

$$V = \pi \int_0^1 \left(\frac{3}{10}+\frac{2}{5}h-\frac{2}{5}h^2\right)^{\!2} \mathrm{d}h = ~???~\mathrm{m}^3$$

Comment: Although you write the the volume unit is cubic meters, your method will give strange units, since your $r$ values are in centimeters while the $h$ values are in meters. It would be better to do as André Nicolas did and do the $h$ values in centimeters as well, so the limits are $0$ to $100$ (or $-50$ to $50$) instead. Then the volume will be in cubic centimeters, or milliliters.

Comment: @RoryDaulton **No**, I'm pretty sure that $\frac{3}{10}\!\mathrm{m} = 0.3~\mathrm{m}=30~\mathrm{cm}$ since $100~\mathrm{cm}=1~\mathrm{m}$. Substitute $h=0,\frac{1}{2},1$ into my $r$ and you'll get $r=\frac{3}{10},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{10}$. If you perform the integration, you'll find that you get the same value as André's method.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I apologize for not reading your answer closely enough. I'll leave my mistaken comment as penance.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Since $h$ is measured in metres and $r$ is measured in metres, then for some small $h$, say $\delta h$, the quantity $\pi r^2~\delta h$ is measured in $\mathrm{m}^3$. Like I said: **try working through the calculations**, you'll find that André's answers is exactly $10^6$ times my answer. His answer is in $\mathrm{cm}^3$ and mine is in $\mathrm{m}^3$. What is the conversion factor? Oh, look: $1~\mathrm{m}^3 = 10^6~\mathrm{cm}^3$.